# specified column width

Tags: tables, width

I'm using the following code for the table. Currently it is set up so that I can change the width of all column (except the first one) to the same width. Can someone help me tweet it so that I can specify the column width every time I use it? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
%%table 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=gray!50,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        every odd row/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!05}
        },
        column 1/.style={
          nodes={text width=5em,font=\bfseries}
        },
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=gray!25,
                text=black,
                text height=2.5ex,
                font=\bfseries, purple!75!black
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table,text width=12em]
{
first & 2nd column   & 3rd column\\
&A & B \\
& C & D \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to put this in the preamble, but that means I have to have the all the tables in the same document to the same width specified, as of now.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please complete your code so it can be compiled? This is really important as it makes your question clearer and easier to answer. In the case of TiKZ, where stuff often requires libraries etc., it is even more crucial.

Comment: Thanks. So what do you want to be able to change exactly? If you add another picture with a table and specify `text width=4em`, the width of the table will be different. So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this so that you can adjust the width of the first column as well as that of the other columns?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle,
      draw=gray!50,
      align=center
    },
    minimum height=1.5em,
    text depth=0.5ex,
    text height=2ex,
    nodes in empty cells,
    %%
    every odd row/.style={
      nodes={fill=gray!05}
    },
    first column text width/.code={%
      \tikzset{
        column 1/.style={
          nodes={text width=##1, font=\bfseries}
        },
      }
    },
    first column text width=5em,
    row 1/.style={
      nodes={
        fill=gray!25,
        text=black,
        text height=2.5ex,
        font=\bfseries, purple!75!black
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[table,text width=12em]
    {
      first & 2nd column   & 3rd column\\
      &A & B \\
      & C & D \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[table,text width=6em, first column text width=3em]
    {
      first & 2nd column   & 3rd column\\
      &A & B \\
      & C & D \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: variant tables]

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Now, just in case... I know this is not a good practice. But what if I want the 2nd column or the 3rd column to have different widths? Also, what if I want the 3rd column to be left justified. Of course these changes are preferably local... Basically I want a versatile setting.

Comment: @SeanN You can duplicate the configuration for column 1 for column 2 and column 3 so that you have separate configuration for each column. You'd need to set this up to override the `align=center` for `nodes` to change the alignment.